# Maven pom.xml dependency

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven, deployment

I've got a maven spring boot project, where there is an ojdbc dependency which looks like this:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ojdbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
        <version>12.2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

And the project with this dependency is already in prod environment.

My question is, what if I change `groupId` from `ojdbc` to `oracle`?
Will it cause any problems when deployment? Maven Package is to `war` file.

Answer (score 0):

If you deploy to a web application server then it provides jdbc usually. In this case, a dependency must be `<scope>provided`.

GroupId changes don't really do anything, it could be another jar but still. You can verify only on deploy

Comment: Sorry but if you change the groupId you change everything cause you don't get the jar you would like to have or may be something what is doing something completely different...